# How can we travel back to time if we go with a speed $>> c$?

Tags: special-relativity

I have read

> "If something attains the speed more than that of light then it can travel back to time."

I want to know how it happens.

Also, in relativity why can nothing acquire velocity beyond $c$?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on your flashlight, then travel faster than the speed of light, you have to wait for your initial flash to arrive. Since the speed of light is a barrier in special relativity, information can never travel faster than $c$. Considering causality you then would have traveled backwards in time.

Having this said, it is impossible to break through that barrier. You are not an will never be able to travel faster than light. There are however hypothetical particles moving faster than the speed of light, called [Tachyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon). But they have some peculiar properties  and live in a *world beyond ours*, meaning that we can never interact with them.

Comment: Are you aware there actually is no evidence for Tachyons?

Comment: @HritikNarayan: That's what I'm saying. They exist in theory, but not only is there no evidence, but there can never be any.